# My image buttons on my masterpage is throwing errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I am using a masterpage and in my leftpanel I have a few imagebuttons, and when I add attributes to them and run my app I get this error...

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I am positive that my image names are correct, here is my code..

```
void BtnAssets()
    {
        imgBtnAssets.Attributes.Add("onmousedown", "src='Images/downassets.png'");
        imgBtnAssets.Attributes.Add("onmouseup", "src='Images/upassets.png'");
    }
```

and when I call it in the pageload method it generates the error that I provided. Sometimes my other imagebuttons work, but for some reason this one in particular isn't working.

Thanks

Comment: is that imgBtnAssets placed on masterpage? where you call BtnAssets?(n master page or any other page)

Comment: @Damith, I made a mistake, I have a contentplaceholder on my master page and I kept dropping my imagebuttons in that and not on the masterpage...but this brings up another question...when working with buttons on the master page, should I use Response.Redirect() to fill my Main content placeholder?